# Load google maps to div loaded by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps

I'm using jquery ajax to get some results from a php script that is parsing an xml document. After that ajax call i whant to show a map from google api, in a div created by that php script (***that's my problem***).

Is it possible to load the maps API to the `<div id="map-canvas">` that is created in php, after the ajax call??

**PHP FILE**

```
    ... $xmlData = simplexml_load_file("using an http service");            
    echo "<div id='map-canvas'></div>";  //LOAD MAPP HERE!
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($xmlData->StopTimes->StopTime as $stopTime){
        echo "<li>",$stopTime->attributes()->Hour,"</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

**AJAX FILE**

```
...
    //station click, show next stops
    $('.station_link').click(function(){
        var station_text = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({                                //make the ajax call
            type: "POST",                       //use POST/GET
            url: "../server_side/nextStop.php", //file to send data
            data: {poststation : station_text},         //postlink -> php($_POST) value / text -> jquery var value
            success: function(data){            //on success, do something
                $('#next_stop').html(data);
                $('#next_stop').show();

            //Google maps API
                 function initialize() {
                      var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                      }
                      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                    }

                    function loadScript() {
                      var script = document.createElement("script");
                      script.type = "text/javascript";
                      script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
                      document.body.appendChild(script);
                    }

                    loadScript();
            }   
            });
        });
    });
```

This is what i've tried (and much more :p), but i dont even know if its just wrong.

Any help or advise would be appreciated!

**-- UPDATE --**

As simple as this:

**javascript file**

```
//station click, show next stops
    $('.station_link').click(function(){
        var station_text = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({                                //make the ajax call
            type: "POST",                       //use POST/GET
            url: "../server_side/nextStop.php", //file to send data
            data: {poststation : station_text}, //postlink -> php($_POST) value / text -> jquery var value
            success: function(data){            //on success, do something
                $('#next_stop').html(data);
                $('#next_stop').show();


                // Google maps API
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831,-122.4039),
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            }   
            });
        });
    });
```

And just adding this `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>` to the HTML file.

That's what i whanted, it´s loading the `<div id="map-canvas">` as it should.

Ty for help anyway!
Sorry if i didn't proove my point earlier, i'm a bit newbie ;)

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps must be loaded at the time you call `center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),`, so from my opinion you should create a dummy map and initialize it on page load

```
<div id="dummy"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initGoogle(){
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dummy'), mapOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.id = 'googleMaps';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initGoogle';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #dummy { position: absolute; top: -5000px; left: -5000px; }
</style>
```

then you can bind whatever you want.

---

Note: I used jQuery's `$(document).ready()`, but if you don't use jQuery you can figure it out.

Comment: Hi mate.
First off all ty for your reply, and yes i'm using jQuery!
Well, i'm testing what you wrote, and shouldn't that "style(top/left)" be as simple as a `display:none` and then show the div with jquery after ajax call?
The bad news is that when i do that the Gmap becomes messed up, all gray and funny :s
Or maybe i misunderstood you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `initialize` isn't getting called due to scope issues as it's only defined in the scope of the Ajax callback and not the global scope, which the Maps SDK will expect.

If you have to load the Google Maps JS asynchronously, use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and then initialise your map in `getScript`'s callback.

It could be better though as you're effectively chaining two requests, which is not particularly performant.

You could:

- Create a global variable set to `0`
- Fire off your Ajax call for the Maps div
- Use `getScript` to load the Maps SDK asynchronously and concurrently
- In the callback function of your Ajax and getScript calls, increment a global variable you just set
- Have a loop that runs every 50ms or so (recursively calling `setTimeout`, for example), checking the value of the variable you set, waiting until it is equal to `2`, set the timeout for another 50ms or so to check again
- Once the condition above is satisfied, initialize your map as you know that both the div and maps API have loaded

Comment: Hey. Thanks for giving me your time. I'm trying another stuff out, maybe i'll try your advice later :)

Answer (score -2):

You can call a js function after AJAX call. You probably better define the function of initialization of gmaps somewhere outside of AJAX call and then after a successful call to your php script call you gmap function (in case of high need with `setTimeout('gmap()', 2000);` function). But as I see your script it first creates div and then calls function of gmap

Comment: Ouch, that's nasty. What if it takes longer than 2000ms to load?